# Whether PCIe Access Control Service(ACS) is enabled or disabled

Tags: pci-e

How to judge whether ACS is enabled or disabled on the device? By looking at the ACS register or something else?

Comment: If you are using linux, the easiest way is running `lspci -vvv` (as root) and find the ACS capability, the register ACSCtl will indicate which feature of ACS is enabled